# Embedd scrollable document faster than PDF possible?

Tags: pdf, scribd

I have a page of about 10 embedded PDF docs. My question is there another option that would use smaller file sizes or something so they don't bogg down the page when visited? Even convert PDF to something else if possible. Right now they are all in an accordion jquery and run with Scribd. Maybe something similar to this would work.:

[scrolling text box](http://oldtoad.net/Demo_1/Scrolling_Text_Box.html)

Comment: Plain text or html will be faster, it depends on what you want, a pdf is a finished product which is not supposed to be changed and you are guaranteed consistent viewing to everyone who has a pdf viewer and allows the user to download it to there system for off line reading (like downloading a brochure). If it is for online reading, make it a normal html document.

Comment: The pdfs are instruction manuals with pics so they can view it online or dl it with embedded scribd. So probably can't do much beyond compressing the pdfs. Sucks how they all have to load when the page is visited.

Comment: If you have to use the pdf's then maybe you could put a brief of what each one is with a view button and don't download it till they click the link. Or put them on different pages, but thats a design decision.

Comment: Yea they have to be on one page. When you click on whatever title it pops open accordion menu style. What would you suggest that would make them download when clicked? They seem to all load in the background at once now and open one at a time when clicked.

Comment: I made it with a jquery example I modified so if you know anything about that, there must be a way to add to not make all divs load at once.

Comment: Basically what I have except in the boxes are embedded iframes from scribd: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Answer (score 0):

If you want the jqueryui to download different data for each tab you need to put an empty div inside each section and then set an on open (I am not familiar with jqueryui but maybe [the activate](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event?) and create an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get the relevant pdf and save it to the empty div.

There are lots of questions about ajax in jqui accordion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624125/jquery-accordion-not-firing-on-ajax-call) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581713/jquery-accordion-loading-via-ajax) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380889/how-to-perform-the-following-ajax-request-on-jquery-accordion) for example.